# Scrapy not crawling or scraping websites like seatgeek/vividseats

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape ticket info from seatgeek, but I am struggling to do so. When I run my code, I get this:

```
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

The idea is that I would input the name of the show/event, scrapy would scrape the URL of each of the performances for the show and then scrape ticket prices, etc. My code is below:

```
import scrapy
from seatgeek import items

class seatgeekSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "seatgeek_spider"
    showname = input("Enter Show name (lower case please): ")
    showname = showname.replace(' ', '-')
    start_urls = "https://seatgeek.com/" + showname + "-tickets.html"

    def parse_performance(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="event-listing-title"]/@href').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url= 'https://seatgeek.com/' + href,
                callback=self.parse_ticketinv,
                method="POST",
                meta={'url': href})

    def parse_ticketinv(self, response):

        price = response.xpath('//span[@class="omnibox__listing__buy__price"]').extract()
        performance = response.xpath('//div[@class="event-detail-words faint-words"]/text()').extract()
        quantity = response.xpath('//div[@class="omnibox__seatview__availability"]/text()').extract()
        seatinfo = response.xpath('//div[@class="omnibox__listing__section"]/text()').extract()

        # creating scrapy items
        item = items.seatgeekItem()
        item['price'] = price
        item['performance'] = performance
        item['quantity'] = quantity
        item['seatinfo'] = seatinfo

        yield item
```

This is my items.py code:

```
import scrapy

class SeatgeekItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    performnace = scrapy.Field()
    quantity = scrapy.Field()
    seatinfo = scrapy.Field()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two immediate problems I can see:

- `start_urls` should be a list; you should see an error like this as well:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  (...)
      raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
  ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
  ```
- By default, the callback used for urls in `start_urls` is `parse()`, which is not defined in your code. Maybe you should rename your `parse_performance()` method?

Also, [spider arguments](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments) are the more common way to get user input.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but now I've got a separate problem.. I can't seem to write the scraped items to  a csv. I will update my original post.

Comment: I think asking a new question would have been better than editing this one, since editing the code hides the original problem, and most of your question and my answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: Fair- will ask a new question. Thank you!